# IntelliJ fails to import gradle project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

IntelliJ fails to import my Gradle project.

The build window shows that the demon gets started on the right side, and on the left side it just displays

```
<project-name> failed <timestamp>
```

And indeed no dependencies get resolved, source folders don't get set.

How do I debug/fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The first step should be to build the project on the command line and make sure it works.

Then locate the log file of IntelliJ: `Help -> Show Log in Finder` does it for me on Mac OS, I guess there is something similar on other platforms.

My log showed:

```
2021-03-16 11:08:31,370 [222013096]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/Users/jschauder/.sdkman/candidates/java/current,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/jschauder/.gradle/daemon,pid=981,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=GB,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=ad74fb8f-4b76-4109-9780-e222fddedd94,javaHome=/Users/jschauder/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.282-zulu/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/jschauder/.gradle/daemon,pid=89910,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=GB,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

The important part is:

```
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/Users/jschauder/.sdkman/candidates/java/current,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/jschauder/.gradle/daemon,pid=981,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=GB,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

```
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=ad74fb8f-4b76-4109-9780-e222fddedd94,javaHome=/Users/jschauder/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.282-zulu/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/jschauder/.gradle/daemon,pid=89910,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=GB,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

I.e. the gradle demon runs with a different JDK than what IntelliJ expects.

To fix this you

1. go into the preferences of Intellij,
2. search for "gradle"
3. And locate the "Gradle JVM" setting and use the JDK path from the "Actual" line in the logs.  In my case `/Users/jschauder/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.282-zulu/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home`

After that importing the project worked just fine.